# Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL when accessing One Drive using Microsoft Graph Client Library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The following code segment using Microsoft Graph Client Library fails while trying to access One Drive contents

```
var items = Graphclient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

It throws the exception

Code: BadRequest
Message: Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.

Fiddler shows an HTTP 400 for the request header. 
  GET /v1.0/me/drives

I checked in Graph explorer and the tenant does work for the same request so why does it fail in code.

I have set the following admin level app permissions Directory.ReadWrite.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, User.ReadWrite.All

The following sections of code do work

```
IGraphServiceDrivesCollectionPage drives = 
Graphclient.Drives.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Fiddler request - GET /v1.0/drives HTTP/1.1

So what am I missing when I am trying to access Graphclient.Me

Comment: any updates? Is it working yet?

Comment: No it is not working

Answer (score 2):

Could you post the scopes from your jwt? The fact that graph explorer is able to execute the exact same call, implies it must be a permissions issue.

I know it sounds silly, but make sure you click the "grant permissions" button after you set permissions that require admin consent.

Comment: I have created the app on the App Registration portal and given the following Application permissions on the same (Directory.ReadWrite.All,Files.ReadWrite.All,Sites.ReadWrite.All,User.ReadWrite.All). I dont see any Grant Permissions button on the App Registration Portal. So what am I missing out here

Comment: I have followed the steps outlined in this article to register my app https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Comment: Permissions that require admin consent aren't automatically in effect by clicking the checkbox in the permissions list, you will have to explicitly give the "OK" from an admin account. This can be done in the way described in step 3 of the link you sent. Or it can be done by clicking a button in the azure active directory portal, this is a tad easier. Simply go to http://aad.portal.azure.com  click on Azure Active Directory>app registrations>view all apps>click on your app>settings>required permissions and then click the Grant permissions button (you will need an admin account for this)

Comment: I have given admin consent by doing "Step 3. Get administrator consent" as listed in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Comment: I am using a personal Microsoft account and not a work or school account. Is there a limitation with the personal account in terms of accessing OneDrive

Comment: Also I noticed that the app added through App Registration Portal is not visible in my Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > View All Apps section

Comment: Since you are trying to use application permissions and not delegated permissions, it shouldn't matter if you use a personal or work account, check out the required permissions at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_list

I'd advise you to make a new stack overflow post about your app not being found. (tip: it's probably related to your app being a v2.0 app if you registered through the portal)

Comment: I have given all the required permissions and the JWT scopes also list the same correctly.

Comment: Could you post the output of your jwt token? (obviously exclude the sensitive data from it), because IF the token lists the actual permissions under "scp:" it means you're retrieving the wrong token. I know that sounds weird but trust me

Comment: I'm having the same issue. When I decode the JWT I get a `roles` field with the permission `Sites.ReadWrite.All`,  `User.ReadWrite.All` , `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and  `Files.ReadWrite.All` listed. Unfortunately I get the same response as Sanjay in my code. All the endpoints linked to drives give this `400 BadRequest - Unable to retrieve user's mySite URL` output.

Comment: All the links in the comments here are now broken :(