# Getting Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL even if the drive exists

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When querying the Graph with the PHP library for a given drive I receive `400 Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL` or `429 Too many requests`.
When I call for example `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/b0633c25-2655-4dfe-a2b2-078e4310deba/drive` with the PHP library it gives this weird result. When I query the same url in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). It works like a charm.

I've set up the permissions as described in the docs and have the E3 Developers subscription that is still valid.

What am I missing?

Comment: What scopes are you requesting and which OAuth grant flow are you using to obtain the token?

Comment: Here are all the used permissions for the app: https://pasteboard.co/Hyhsgq0.jpg

I'm using the flow to get access without a user logged in: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service
The admin consent is granted and I see the corresponding permissions on the AAD Enterprise Applications page. I'm using the `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` scope to request the access token.

The token seems to work as I can query `/users` successfully.

Comment: Have you changed _any_ scopes after going through Admin Consent? Also, you can remove all those Delegated scopes (they only apply to AuthCode/Implicit grants) as well as the `.Read.` Application scopes since you already have `.ReadWrite.` selected.

Comment: I did not change any of the scopes. As a way to reset all the granted permissions I removed the application from the AAD Enterprise Applications and went through the permission grant flow again.
Unfortunately this gives exactly the same output.

Comment: Graph Explorer is using Delegated scopes which operate differently so that isn't a very good comparison. Are you able to retrieve metadata from `/users/{id}`? Do you get anything from `/users/{id}/drives` (note `drives` instead of `drive`)

Comment: I'm able to retrieve all the data from `/users/{id}`. The `/users/{id}/drives` gives the same result as `/users/{id}/drive`.
`"code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.",`

Comment: It sure sounds like they don't have a ODfB provisioned. Are you able to view this user's OneDrive using the web UI?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to view this user's OneDrive: https://pasteboard.co/HyvfbUj.png
When I perform the same query in the Graph Explorer I receive all the metadata: https://pastebin.com/CMgQ3aT6
The issue is not related to just one user, I receive this message for all the users. Also when requesting the drive (`/users/{id}/drive`) for all my users, I receive a `429` after only 4 queries. Honestly, I don't think that's expected behavior either...

Comment: Further debugging: when I copy the access token from the Graph Explorer, and use that token it works. Using my own token it doesn't and I'm getting throttled all the time.
Strange thing is my token works for getting all the users in the tenant (`/users`).

Comment: Screenshots from the AAD enterprise applications permission page: [Admin consent](https://pasteboard.co/HyyDd8a.jpg), [user consent](https://pasteboard.co/HyyDiHd.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the token you're getting as well as the one from Graph Explorer? It might be helpful to compare the two.

Comment: I'll send you a PM with the tokens, as I don't want to provide them in public

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL when accessing One Drive using Microsoft Graph Client Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710952/unable-to-retrieve-users-mysite-url-when-accessing-one-drive-using-microsoft-gr)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is misleading and does not mention billing as it should.

Check your Billing > Your Products (subscription) in your Microsoft 365 Admin and then try again.

The best way to test is:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Answer (score 0):

The current error seems like user does not have ODFB(OneDrive For Business) site created, you can check if the user have create OneDrive site(the OneDrive site will be created while the user first time to use it).

To debug that issue for now, try to use Graph Explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer# and login with your user account.
If you can access /me then try accessing /me/drive/root and you will get details about ODFB Doc Lib for current user if it exist.
we can get results with the following link for login-in user

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
```

Reference for you: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1354

Comment: Awesome copy-paste! I already stumbled upon that issue. As I stated in my question: "When I query the same url in the Graph Explorer. It works like a charm.". So it's not related to ODFB(OneDrive For Business) site

Comment: Not pure copy-paste. I have  tested it on my side. I have really O365 enterprise account for testing and we have face many the ODFB issues.

Comment: Because I cannot repro your issue on my side, so i can just suggest you check the permission or check the ODFB site. If you sure both of them are OK, you can submit the issue, but the PG maybe redirect it to stackoverflow again.

Comment: Rechecked the permissions according to the docs -> OK. Visited the users site ->OK. Tried the same query again -> NOK.

Comment: Do you have try another user, so we can confirm if it is a common issue or just for the one tester user?

Comment: I've multiple users, and unfortunately they all get the same error message. About 50% of the users actually have files in their onedrive. So the onedrive exists...