# Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL - Microsoft Graph, Error 500

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I saw similar topics but I didn't see the solution. I use Office 365 business account. I created my application in the Azure portal, I set appropriate permissions.

If I make a request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users Everything is fine. If I want to get something from "drive" e.g.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children then I have a mistake:

> "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL."

This is error 500

What should I do to get access? Ultimately, I want to get data from the excel sheet that I added to my company OneDrive.

Comment: an HTTP 4xx error is YOUR mistake. An HTTP 5xx error is THEIR mistake. Given that your request was valid (not 400) then I'm afraid microsoft are at fault and there's not much you can do.

Comment: :( How else can I download data about my excel file?

Comment: Try it from incognito tab, sometime it helps

Comment: I see the same error. Any more ideas?

Comment: Do you know any other API that will allow me to get data from excel file? Accurate data from columns, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL when accessing One Drive using Microsoft Graph Client Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710952/unable-to-retrieve-users-mysite-url-when-accessing-one-drive-using-microsoft-gr)